# Writing bytes to file gets swapped on certain platforms

Tags: c, io, posix, fwrite

The following code gives me different outputs on different systems:

```
int fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
byte_t data[] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x0a, 0x0b 0x0c, 0x0d };

write(fd, data, sizeof(data));
```

On the mac a 'hexdump' of the filename gives what I would expect

```
00 01 02 03 0a 0b 0c 0d
```

On Ubuntu and on Windows ( the code is different but the effect is the same ) you get

```
01 00 03 02 0b 0a 0d 0c
```

I would like platforms to print

```
00 01 02 03 0a 0b 0c 0d
```

So how should I proceed?

Comment: is "byte_t" a consistent data type across the two platforms?

Comment: "the code is different"? Please show us the *actual* code, not some approximation.

Comment: I think it's highly unlikely that the code you show would behave in the manner you describe on *any* platform (regardless of endianness etc). Please include an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Looks like ENDIANNESS issue. Although not quite typical. Have a look at these [IMB write endian independent code](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/) and [some random doc I found on google](http://www.slashdocs.com/uquyk/writing-endian-independent-code-in-c.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help guys, I ended up learning a bit more about possible endianness issues than I would have otherwise.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz byte_t is consistent across all platforms I've used, I could have written unsigned char but I wanted to communicate that I was just passing in bytes

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Intel Mac, it's a mac mini and my code didn't stark getting weird until I tried to use other platforms

Comment: Thank you for the links NPE and David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the hexdump utility swaps the bytes. Please show the hexdump command you used in each platform.

To confirm it, test with

```
byte_t data[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' }
```

and compare the hexdump and cat(or type) outputs.

Comment: I tested my output with xxd and the data was printed out in correct order. Hexdump still shows the bytes reverse. I think you are right, it's just the way that hexdump behaves on certain platforms on not the data being written out with bytes swapped.

Comment: What options were you using to `hexdump`?

Comment: I didn't use any options ( maybe I should have ). File was named mywave.wav so I wrote:
    hexdump mywave.wav

Comment: @user Yes. "-C" in Linux.